# JavaScript: How do I dynamically "filter" my objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I user the JavaScript "`filter`" attribute as filter my JavaScript object?

I've been reading the following [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694717/javascript-how-to-create-an-object-and-filter-on-those-attributes), and am in a similar situation.

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
{
'cars' : 
[{
"car_id"          : "1",
"price"           : "42999",
"make_id"         : "050",
"year_built"      : "2007",
"color_id"        : "832"
},
..........
]}
```

I'm using JQuery to display controls to allow people to filter based on: Price, Make, Year Built, Color

Per that other post, I can use the following code:

```
// if using an old browser, define the 'filter' attribute
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array();
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
      {
        var val = this[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

then to perform the actual filter, I can do:

```
result = cars.
  filter(function(p) { return p.price >= 15000 }).
  filter(function(p) { return p.price <= 40000 }).
  filter(function(p) { return p.year_built >= 2000 }) etc
```

**What I don't understand is, how do I use my JQuery controls to dynamically change the `filter` once the filter has already been set?** Meaning, let's say I have the filter applied from above, *then* the user changes there mind and wants to increase the maximum they are willing to pay for a car from $40,000 to $50,000.

How would I problematically modify my filter from :

```
  filter(function(p) { return p.price <= 40000 }).
```

to:

```
  filter(function(p) { return p.price <= 50000 }).
```

Answer (score 4):

> how do I use my JQuery controls to dynamically change the filter once the filter has already been set?

You don't **set** a filter. You call `filter()` with a filter function and get a filtered array back; you can't change the filter that was applied to the array afterwards. Instead you must call `filter()` again, and pass a different filter function.

Or the same filter function with a closure over a variable that has changed:

```
var minprice= 10000;
var minpricefilter= function(p) { return p.price>=minprice };
result= cars.filter(minpricefilter);

minprice= 20000;
result= cars.filter(minpricefilter);
```

Comment: This is a sloppier form of my solution, but the look at the filter reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function generator.

```
function createPriceFilter(price)
{
   filter =  function(){ return p.price >= price };
   return filter;
}
```

Then, when you filter, always use a function generator.

```
cars
    .filter( createPriceFilter( mySelectedPrice ) )
    .filter( createSomethingFilter(...) )
    . (...)
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand JavaScript enough but how does this help exactly? Isn't this simply performing the exact same task but now requiring me to create functions instead

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `filter`, how about a plain old loop:

```
var min_year = 2000;
var min_price = 15000;
var max_price = 40000;

function fillTable() {
    clearTheTable();
    for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        var car = cars[i];
        if (p.price >= min_price && p.price <= max_price && p.year_built >= min_year)
            addCarToTable(car);
    }
}
```

Each time your parameters change, just call `fillTable()` again to regenerate the whole table.

(There are much cleverer things you can do but this is the simplest thing I could think of.)

Answer (score 0):

Forget callback based filtering. Enter jOrder: http://github.com/danstocker/jorder.

Filtering by iterating over your entire table is tedious and slow. With jOrder, you search by index:

```
var table = jOrder(json.cars)
    .index('id', ['car_id'])
    .index('price', ['price'], { grouped: true, ordered: true, type: jOrder.number })
    .index('maker', ['maker_id'], { grouped: true })
    .index('year', ['year_built'], { grouped: true, ordered: true, type: jOrder.number })
    .index('color', ['color_id'], { grouped: true });
```

Then you get the records you want by:

```
var filtered = table.where([{ price: { lower: 15000, upper: 40000 } }], { mode: jOrder.range });
```

Note that you can only apply one inequality filter at a time. To do more, use `filtered` as an input for a different jOrder table, put only the necessary index on it, and perform the second inequality filter on that one. And so on. Even if you stack up a couple of filters like this, it will be still faster than iteration by a factor of about 10 to 100 depending on the size of your table.