# How to filter object array based on attributes?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript array of real estate home objects:

```
var json = {
    'homes': [{
            "home_id": "1",
            "price": "925",
            "sqft": "1100",
            "num_of_beds": "2",
            "num_of_baths": "2.0",
        }, {
            "home_id": "2",
            "price": "1425",
            "sqft": "1900",
            "num_of_beds": "4",
            "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        },
        // ... (more homes) ...     
    ]
}

var xmlhttp = eval('(' + json + ')');
homes = xmlhttp.homes;
```

What I would like to do is be able to perform a filter on the object to return a subset of "home" objects.

For example, I want to be able to filter based on: `price`, `sqft`, `num_of_beds`, and `num_of_baths`.

How can I perform something in JavaScript like the pseudo-code below:

```
var newArray = homes.filter(
    price <= 1000 & 
    sqft >= 500 & 
    num_of_beds >=2 & 
    num_of_baths >= 2.5 );
```

Note, the syntax does not have to be exactly like above. This is just an example.

Comment: This seems almost identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694717/javascript-how-to-create-an-object-and-filter-on-those-attributes

Comment: `var json = { ... }` JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Don't use eval. It's generally bad practice and can cause performance issues. We just had to get rid of a bunch of those on a project because the processor was locking up.

Comment: 2022-
Just observed that 'return' is needed inside the filter function like in @Christian.C.Salvado's answer

Answer (score 996, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var newArray = homes.filter(function (el) {
  return el.price <= 1000 &&
         el.sqft >= 500 &&
         el.num_of_beds >=2 &&
         el.num_of_baths >= 2.5;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var obj = {
    'homes': [{
            "home_id": "1",
            "price": "925",
            "sqft": "1100",
            "num_of_beds": "2",
            "num_of_baths": "2.0",
        }, {
            "home_id": "2",
            "price": "1425",
            "sqft": "1900",
            "num_of_beds": "4",
            "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        },
        // ... (more homes) ...     
    ]
};
// (Note that because `price` and such are given as strings in your object,
// the below relies on the fact that <= and >= with a string and number
// will coerce the string to a number before comparing.)
var newArray = obj.homes.filter(function (el) {
  return el.price <= 1000 &&
         el.sqft >= 500 &&
         el.num_of_beds >= 2 &&
         el.num_of_baths >= 1.5; // Changed this so a home would match
});
console.log(newArray);
```

This method is part of the new [ECMAScript 5th Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) standard, and can be found on almost all modern browsers.

For IE, you can include the following method for compatibility:

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = [];
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in this) {
        var val = this[i];
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }
    return res;
  };
}
```

Comment: @JGreig: Is just a comment to indicate that an optional argument may be passed, the argument is not specified directly because the ECMA standard precisely says that this method should expect only one argument (`Array.prototype.filter.length == 1;`). When you use the second argument, it will be used as the `this` value inside the callback function.

Comment: @CMS, Are you sure this code works? This is returning an empty array, even when I set the price to be really high and the sqft/beds/baths to be really low. Are you sure this code works?

Comment: @JGreig: Yes, it works, you should check your criteria, maybe you could post a more complete example of your JSON in http://pastie.org or http://jsbin.com and the criteria you are using to filter, so I can help you better.

Comment: @CMS, I've updated my original post with the live web site. It would be great if you could look at the code. I really, really appreciate it. Thanks in advance

Comment: @JGreig, you're welcome!, don't forget to include the compatibility method for IE...

Comment: FYI, if the block in `.filter(function(object) {})` returns `true` it will be kept, if it returns `false` it will **not** be kept

Comment: @CMS It would be good if the answer includes the fact that a new array is returned, the original array is not modified. Even though this is said in the link provided, I find the answer without this is incomplete or inaccurate

Comment: @CMS could you give a plunker / jsfiddle demo of the complete code please

Answer (score 63):

I'm surprised no one has posted the one-line response:

```
const filteredHomes = json.homes.filter(x => x.price <= 1000 && x.sqft >= 500 && x.num_of_beds >=2 && x.num_of_baths >= 2.5);
```

...and just so you can read it easier:

```
const filteredHomes = json.homes.filter( x => 
  x.price <= 1000 && 
  x.sqft >= 500 && 
  x.num_of_beds >=2 && 
  x.num_of_baths >= 2.5
);
```

Comment: probably because it's the same as [CMS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2722213/4468423) just with arrow functions

Comment: It becomes a better answer with the newer versions of javascript for sure. var should be replaced with const, from my understanding.

Comment: @Erich you have no idea how many people blindly copy and paste from SO. Rn I'm working on a project born in 2021, transpiled, and it's full of `var _self = this`

Answer (score 33):

You can try using framework like jLinq - following is a code sample of using jLinq

```
var results = jLinq.from(data.users)
.startsWith("first", "a")
.orEndsWith("y")
.orderBy("admin", "age")
.select();
```

For more information you can follow the link http://www.hugoware.net/projects/jlinq

Answer (score 31):

I prefer the Underscore framework. It suggests many useful operations with objects.
Your task:

```
var newArray = homes.filter(
    price <= 1000 & 
    sqft >= 500 &
    num_of_beds >=2 & 
    num_of_baths >= 2.5);
```

can be overwriten like:

```
var newArray = _.filter (homes, function(home) {
    return home.price<=1000 && sqft>=500 && num_of_beds>=2 && num_of_baths>=2.5;
});
```

Hope it will be useful for you!

Comment: How does this underscore thing work and what exactly does it mean?

Comment: Just discovered `underscore-query` (https://github.com/davidgtonge/underscore-query) which uses MongoDB-like syntax to query javascript arrays.  So here you'd use `_.query(homes, {price: {$lt:1000}, sqft: {$gte: 500}, num_of_beds: {$gte:2}, num_of_baths: {$gte: 2.5}}`

Answer (score 14):

use filter

```js
var json = {
    homes: [{
            "home_id": "1",
            "price": "925",
            "sqft": "1100",
            "num_of_beds": "2",
            "num_of_baths": "2.0",
        }, {
            "home_id": "2",
            "price": "1425",
            "sqft": "1900",
            "num_of_beds": "4",
            "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        },
         
    ]
}


let filter = 
  json.homes.filter(d => 
  
    d.price >= 1000 & 
    d.sqft >= 500 & 
    d.num_of_beds >=2 & 
    d.num_of_baths >= 2.5
)

console.log(filter)
```

Comment: how is this different from [Christian C. Salvadó's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2722213/4468423) or its [earlier duplicate by Lou Bagel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56370992/4468423)?

Answer (score 12):

here is the working fiddle which works fine in IE8 using jquery MAP function

http://jsfiddle.net/533135/Cj4j7/

```
json.HOMES = $.map(json.HOMES, function(val, key) {
    if (Number(val.price) <= 1000
            && Number(val.sqft) >= 500
            && Number(val.num_of_beds) >=2
            && Number(val.num_of_baths ) >= 2.5)
        return val;
});
```

Answer (score 12):

This question was asked with multiple results in mind, in which case `filter` is the way to go, as the other answerers here already pointed out.

However, since this question has become a popular duplicate target, I ought to mention that if you are looking for **just a single element satisfying the condition**, you don't need `filter` and can instead use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). It works the same way but it simply returns the first matching element or `undefined` if no elements match, instead of returning an array of matches:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, value: 10 },
  { id: 2, value: 20 },
  { id: 3, value: 30 }
]

console.log(data.filter(o => o.value > 15))
// Output: [{ id: 2, value: 20 }, { id: 3, value: 30 }]

console.log(data.find(o => o.value > 15))
// Output: { id: 2, value: 20 }

console.log(data.filter(o => o.value > 100))
// Output: []

console.log(data.find(o => o.value > 100))
// Output: undefined

// `find` is often useful to find an element by some kind of ID:
console.log(data.find(o => o.id === 3))
// Output: { id: 3, value: 30 }
```

Answer (score 9):

You could do this pretty easily - there are probably many implementations you can choose from, but this is my basic idea (and there is probably some format where you can iterate over an object with jQuery, I just cant think of it right now):

```
function filter(collection, predicate)
{
    var result = new Array();
    var length = collection.length;

    for(var j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        if(predicate(collection[j]) == true)
        {
             result.push(collection[j]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then you could invoke this function like so:

```
filter(json, function(element)
{
    if(element.price <= 1000 && element.sqft >= 500 && element.num_of_beds > 2 && element.num_of_baths > 2.5)
        return true;

    return false;
});
```

This way, you can invoke the filter based on whatever predicate you define, or even filter multiple times using smaller filters.

Comment: Please change "int length" to "var length" in the first snippet

Answer (score 9):

You can use jQuery.grep() since jQuery 1.0:

```
$.grep(homes, function (h) {
  return h.price <= 1000
    && h.sqft >= 500
    && h.num_of_beds >= 2
    && h.num_of_baths >= 2.5
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const y = 'search text';
const a = [{key: "x", "val: "y"},  {key: "d", "val: "z"}]
const data = a.filter(res => {
        return(JSON.stringify(res).toLocaleLowerCase()).match(y.toLocaleLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I use my `ruleOut` function for filtering objects based on **specific unwanted property values.** I understand that in your example you would like to use conditions instead of values, but my answer is valid for the question title, so I'd like to leave my method here.

```
function ruleOut(arr, filterObj, applyAllFilters=true) {    
    return arr.filter( row => {            
        for (var field in filterObj) {
            var val = row[field];
            if (val) {                    
                if (applyAllFilters && filterObj[field].indexOf(val) > -1) return false;                
                else if (!applyAllFilters) {                        
                    return filterObj[field].filter(function(filterValue){ 
                        return (val.indexOf(filterValue)>-1);
                    }).length == 0;                 
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Say you have a list of actors like this:

```
let actors = [
  {userName:"Mary", job:"star", language:"Turkish"},
  {userName:"John", job:"actor", language:"Turkish"},
  {userName:"Takis", job:"star", language:"Greek"},
  {userName:"Joe", job:"star", language:"Turkish"},
  {userName:"Bill", job:"star", language:"Turkish"}
];
```

and you would like to find all actors that are rated as Holywood stars, their nationality should not be one of 'English', 'Italian', 'Spanish', 'Greek', plus their name would not be one of 'Mary', 'Joe'. Bizzar example, I know! Anyway, with that set of conditions you would create the following object:

```
let unwantedFieldsFilter= { 
  userName: ['Mary', 'Joe'],    
  job: ['actor'],   
  language: ['English', 'Italian', 'Spanish', 'Greek']  
};
```

OK, now if you `ruleOut(actors, unwantedFieldsFilter)` you would only get

> [{userName: "Bill", job: "star", language: "Turkish"}]

And Bill is your man, since his name is not one of 'Mary', 'Joe', his nationality is not included in ['English', 'Italian', 'Spanish', 'Greek'] plus he is a Star!

There is one option in my method, that is `applyAllFilters` and is true by default.
If you would try to ruleOut with this param set as false, that would work as an 'OR' filtering instead of 'AND'. 
Example: `ruleOut(actors, {job:["actor"], language:["Italian"]}, false)` would get you everyone that is not an actor or Italian:

> [{userName: "Mary", job: "star", language: "Turkish"},
>   {userName: "Takis", job: "star", language: "Greek"},
>   {userName: "Joe", job: "star", language: "Turkish"},
>   {userName: "Bill", job: "star", language: "Turkish"}]

Comment: VM586:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ruleOut is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: @MohammadAyoubKhan  Copy my code (ruleOut, actors & unwantedFieldsFilter definitions) in the browser console and run ruleOut(actors, unwantedFieldsFilter) as in my example, it works fine. Obviously you have an invocation out of scope. Also notice that just pasting an error is not helpful nor polite, just saying!

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a filter method yourself that meets your needs, here is how:

```
function myfilter(array, test){
    var passedTest =[];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if(test( array[i]))
          passedTest.push(array[i]);
    }

    return passedTest;
}

var passedHomes = myfilter(homes,function(currentHome){
     return ((currentHome.price <= 1000 )&& (currentHome.sqft >= 500 )&&(currentHome.num_of_beds >=2 )&&(currentHome.num_of_baths >= 2.5));
});
```

Hope, it helps!

Comment: My predicate condition changes from various onclicks. How can store the current predicate values and apply it to myfilter function whenever I want to?

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [OGX.List](https://github.com/globules-io/OGX.JS/wiki/list) which has built in filtering methods and extends the standard javascript array (and also grouping, sorting and finding). Here's a list of operators it supports for the filters:

```
'eq' //Equal to
'eqjson' //For deep objects, JSON comparison, equal to
'neq' //Not equal to
'in' //Contains
'nin' //Doesn't contain
'lt' //Lesser than
'lte' //Lesser or equal to
'gt' //Greater than
'gte' //Greater or equal to
'btw' //Between, expects value to be array [_from_, _to_]
'substr' //Substring mode, equal to, expects value to be array [_from_, _to_, _niddle_]
'regex' //Regex match
```

You can use it this way

```
  let list = new OGX.List(your_array);
  list.addFilter('price', 'btw', 100, 500);
  list.addFilter('sqft', 'gte', 500);
  let filtered_list = list.filter();
```

Or even this way

```
  let list = new OGX.List(your_array);
  let filtered_list = list.get({price:{btw:[100,500]}, sqft:{gte:500}});
```

Or as a one liner

```
   let filtered_list = new OGX.List(your_array).get({price:{btw:[100,500]}, sqft:{gte:500}});
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simply use `$.each` (which also works for objects, not only arrays) and build a new array like so:

```
var json = {
    'homes': [{
            "home_id": "1",
            "price": "925",
            "sqft": "1100",
            "num_of_beds": "2",
            "num_of_baths": "2.0",
        }, {
            "home_id": "2",
            "price": "1425",
            "sqft": "1900",
            "num_of_beds": "4",
            "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        },
        // ... (more homes) ...     
        {
            "home_id": "3-will-be-matched",
            "price": "925",
            "sqft": "1000",
            "num_of_beds": "2",
            "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        },
    ]
}

var homes = [];
$.each(json.homes, function(){
    if (this.price <= 1000
        && this.sqft >= 500
        && this.num_of_beds >= 2
        && this.num_of_baths >= 2.5
    ) {
        homes.push(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var filterHome = homes.filter(home =>
  return (home.price <= 999 &&
         home.num_of_baths >= 2.5 &&
         home.num_of_beds >=2 &&
         home.sqft >= 998));
console.log(filterHome);
```

You can use this lambda function. More detail can be found here since we are filtering the data based on you have condition which return true or false and it will collect the data in different array so your actual array will be not modified.

@JGreig Please look into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
const state.contactList = [{
    name: 'jane',
    email: 'jane@gmail.com'
  },{},{},...]

const fileredArray = state.contactsList.filter((contactItem) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${action.payload}`, 'gi');
  return contactItem.nameProperty.match(regex) || 
    contactItem.emailProperty.match(regex);
});


// contactList: all the contacts stored in state
// action.payload: whatever typed in search field
```

Answer (score 1):

advance code for the search for all attributes of the object in arrays

```
b=[]; 
yourArray.forEach(x => {
      Object.keys(x).forEach(i => {if (x[i].match('5') && !b.filter(y => y === x).length) { b.push(x) }})
    });
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach

```
const filterOutputs = [];
json.homes.forEach((home) => {
if (
parseInt(home.price) <= 1000 &&
parseInt(home.sqft) >= 500 &&
parseInt(home.num_of_beds) >= 2 &&
parseInt(home.num_of_baths) >= 2
) {
filterOutputs.push(home);
}
});

console.log(filterOutputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one case is not covered and maybe someone looks for matching case as I did. Case when someone wants to filter by property value which is string or number using filtering as "where matches" conditional, let's say by city name etc. In other words like Query: return array of ALL homes WHERE city = "Chicago". Solution is simple:

```
  const filterByPropertyValue = (cityName) => {
    let filteredItems = homes.filter((item) => item.city === cityName);
    console.log("FILTERED HOMES BY CITY:", filteredItems);
  }
```

In case you need to trigger it programmatically or from looping / mapping array in HTML as  or  by providing 'city' value (you can provide array as well just add it in function to reuse function):

```
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                filterByPropertyValue("Chicago");
              }}
            >
              Chicago Homes Only
            </button>
```

Let's say JSON has city property added:

```
'homes': [{
        "home_id": "1",
        "price": "925",
        "sqft": "1100",
        "num_of_beds": "2",
        "num_of_baths": "2.0",
        "city":"Chicago",
    }, {
        "home_id": "2",
        "price": "1425",
        "sqft": "1900",
        "num_of_beds": "4",
        "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        "city":"Chicago",
    },
    // ... (more homes) ...     
    {
        "home_id": "3-will-be-matched",
        "price": "925",
        "sqft": "1000",
        "num_of_beds": "2",
        "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        "city":"Atlanta",
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering data using an array

```
const pickupData = [
    {
      id: 2876635,
      pickup_location: "6311cdacf6b493647d86",
      address_type: null,
      address: "999, Jagarati",``
      address_2: "Vihar",
      updated_address: false,
      old_address: "",
      old_address2: "",
      city: "Meerut",
      state: "Uttar Pradesh",
      country: "India",
      pin_code: "250001",
      email: "938@gmail.com",
      is_first_mile_pickup: 0,
      phone: "76898",
      name: "Aa",
      company_id: 2889808,
      gstin: null,
      vendor_name: null,
      status: 2,
      phone_verified: 1,
      lat: null,
      long: null,
      warehouse_code: null,
      alternate_phone: null,
      rto_address_id: 2867270,
      lat_long_status: 0,
      new: 1,
      associated_rto_address: null
    },
    {
      id: 2872407,
      pickup_location: "6311cdad490cf6b493647d82",
      address_type: null,
      address: "Nagar",
      address_2: "Delhi",
      updated_address: false,
      old_address: "",
      old_address2: "",
      city: "Bijnor",
      state: "Uttar Pradesh",
      country: "India",
      pin_code: "246701",
      email: "ima@gmail.com",
      is_first_mile_pickup: 0,
      phone: "75398",
      name: "Amit Sharma",
      company_id: 2889808,
      gstin: null,
      vendor_name: null,
      status: 1,
      phone_verified: 1,
      lat: null,
      long: null,
      warehouse_code: null,
      alternate_phone: null,
      rto_address_id: 2867270,
      lat_long_status: 0,
      new: 1,
      associated_rto_address: null
    }
  ];
```

const shiprocketData = [
{
line1: "999, Jagarati",
line2: "Vihar",
city: "Meerut",
state: "Uttar Pradesh",
pincode: 250001,
country: "India",
isCurrent: true,
_id: "6311cdad490cf6b3647d86"
},
{
line1: "999, Jagarati",
line2: "Vihar",
city: "Meerut",
state: "Uttar Pradesh",
pincode: 250001,
country: "India",
isCurrent: true,
_id: "6311cdad490cb493647d82"
},
{
line1: "999, Jagarati",
line2: "Vihar",
city: "Meerut",
state: "Uttar Pradesh",
pincode: 250001,
country: "India",
isCurrent: true,
_id: "6311cdad490cf693647d89"
}
];

```
const updatedData = () => {
    const data = pickupData.filter(
      (item, index) =>
        item.pickup_location === shiprocketData.map((item) => item._id)[index]
    );
    return console.log(data);
  };
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This question is asked more than 12 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer

Answer (score 0):

```
**

The simplest way to search a specific value in an Array of Object
--------------------------------------------------------------------

filter() -> uses a callback function the return value of which decides what will be returned in the filtered array. If the return value is true, the item is included in the resultant array.

includes() -> searches for something in an array of items using == equality
**

       const words = [{id:1,name:"tim"},{id:2,name:"morgon"}]
        
          function searchHandler(enteredString){
          const formatedString = enteredString.toLowerCase();
          const result = words.filter(data=> data?.name?.includes(formatedString));
          console.log(result);
    }
```